# How do i split a matrix and then display its minimum and maximum using javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix, split

I have a matrix

```
const matrix = [
      [1,5,7],
      [7,3,5],
      [2,6,9]
];
```

I would like to split it into sub-matrices

```
[
 [1,5],
 [7,3]
]
[
 [5,7],
 [3,5]
]
[
 [7,3],
 [2,6]
]
[
 [3,5],
 [6,9]
]
```

Then I want to get the maximum values from the sub-matrices

```
[
 [7,7],
 [7,9]
]
```

and also the minimum values.

```
[
  [1,3],
  [2,3]
]
```

How can I approach this?

Comment: do you want  the parts as well as min and max? or just min and max?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) are also recommended.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want the parts as well as min and max

Answer (score 0):

Since the dimensions of the original matrix and the dimensions of the submatrices are not specified, I took the ones given in the example:

```
// main function
public static void functionMatrix() {
    int[][] matrix = {{1, 5, 7}, {7, 3, 5}, {2, 6, 9}};

    int[][] matrixResultMax = new int[matrix.length - 1][matrix[0].length - 1];
    int[][] matrixResultMin = new int[matrix.length - 1][matrix[0].length - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length - 1; j++) {
            //Submatrix elements
            System.out.println("[");
            System.out.println("[ " + matrix[i][j] + ", " + matrix[i][j + 1] + " ],");
            System.out.println("[ " + matrix[i + 1][j] + ", " + matrix[i + 1][j + 1] + " ]");
            matrixResultMax[i][j] = Math.max(Math.max(matrix[i][j], matrix[i][j + 1]), Math.max(matrix[i + 1][j], matrix[i + 1][j + 1]));
            matrixResultMin[i][j] = Math.min(Math.min(matrix[i][j], matrix[i][j + 1]), Math.min(matrix[i + 1][j], matrix[i + 1][j + 1]));
            System.out.println("]");
        }
    }

    printMatrix(matrixResultMax);
    printMatrix(matrixResultMin);
}

//new Function
public static void printMatrix(int[][] matr) {
    for (int[] ints : matr) {
        for (int anInt : ints) {
            System.out.print(anInt + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```